# Unable to increment Counter using linq

Tags: vb.net, linq

Hello All
So i am trying to edit and insert rows into a datatable using linq but i am unable to increment the counter using Linq
Basically what i am trying to do is first edit or the data using **Select** method and assigning it to variable in my query using **let** and then using normal **Add** method to add all the rows into the dt SO my first question is can i directly add all the rows without needing the counter ? 
The reason i need counter is what i am trying to do is take one element per iteration using its index for example x(1).....x(n) so for the index i need counter so for counter i created a variable outside the flow and incremented it inside our linq query but it didnt work out.....
The code i have tried
 

**(From roww In DT.AsEnumerable() Let x=DT.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) CStr(r("Column1")).Substring(0,3) ).ToArray Select
DT.Clone.Rows.Add(roww.Item("Some Column"),roww.Item("Column1"),x)).CopyToDataTable**

**(From roww In DT.AsEnumerable() Let x=DT.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) CStr(r("Column1")).Substring(0,3) ).ToArray Select
DT.Clone.Rows.Add(roww.Item("Some Column"),roww.Item("Column1"),x(y+1))).CopyToDataTable**

Another thing what i was looking to use  **Expression.Increment Method** but i havent used it dont know what exactly it is and whether it can be converted to int 
ANy inputs ??

Comment: You have a number of problems: 1) LINQ is for _querying_, not for modifying data. You should not be using `Add` in a LINQ expression 2) you are storing `x`, a `string` array, in a column - that is unlikely to be correct. Also, where in your code is any reference to a counter?

Comment: Yes @NetMage i understand but its just like killing two birds with one stone it does the job very well.... and yes now i have updated the second code which i used to increment the counter sorry for that .......

Comment: I would suggest it doesn't do the method very well, or you wouldn't be asking how to do it. Your code has no increment operator because that isn't allowed in VB. Since VB requires statements, your code is still a syntax error unless you assign it to a variable. Having said that, I think you want the `Zip` method.

Comment: Hello @NetMage what is a zip method ? ................as you can see the code here (From roww In DT.AsEnumerable() Let x=DT.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(r) CStr(r("Column1")).Substring(0,3) ).ToArray Select DT.Clone.Rows.Add(roww.Item("Some Column"),roww.Item("Column1"),x(y+1))).CopyToDataTable

it contains x(y+1) which is the list i got from select statement in this very code and

Comment: Sorry, [`Enumerable.Zip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.zip?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Linq_Enumerable_Zip__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__). Another option if you weren't just processing the same row the hard way, would be to use `Enumerable.Range` and `Zip` with that.

Comment: hello @NetMage can you give me more details about this Enumberable.Zip method i tried using enumerable.range but as it'll give me collection i later cannot convert it to my datatable

Comment: I added an answer explaining how `Enumerable.Range` and `Zip` would make your original attempt work, though still not the best way to do it in this particular case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While your answer is the correct solution to your query, if you had some other type of array not dependent on your original data source, you may need to index into the array in parallel with your data source. While a `For`..`Next` would be the best way to handle this, you can emulate the same effect with LINQ using `Enumerable.Range` and `Zip`.

The `Let` statement is translated into a `Select` that carries the `Let` variable value along with each row. The `Enumerable.Range` provides a source of increasing integers you can use to index into an array.

```
Dim addedDT = (DT.AsEnumerable() _
                 .Select(Function(roww) New With { Key .x = DT.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(r) CStr(r("Column1")).Substring(0,3)).ToArray, roww }) _
                 .Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, DT.Rows.Count), Function(xroww, y) DT.Clone.Rows.Add(xroww.roww.Item("Some Column"),xroww.roww.Item("Column1"),xroww.x(y+1))
              ).CopyToDataTable
```

Looking at the `Let` translation makes it more apparent that the calculation of `x` occurs once per data source row and is very inefficient. Pulling the constant value out makes for a better version:

```
Dim x = DT.AsEnumerable.Select(Function(r) CStr(r("Column1")).Substring(0,3)).ToArray
Dim addedDT = (DT.AsEnumerable() _
                 .Zip(Enumerable.Range(0, DT.Rows.Count), Function(roww, y) DT.Clone.Rows.Add(roww.Item("Some Column"),roww.Item("Column1"),x(y+1))
              ).CopyToDataTable
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello all i did the above question using this query
**(From roww In DT.AsEnumerable() Select
DT.Clone.Rows.Add(roww.Item("Some other data"),roww.Item("Column1"),CStr(roww.Item("Column1")).Substring(0,4))).CopyToDataTable**

But i still want to know how can i increment counter if any one knows how to do it please let me know.......Even if its in C#'s format ill learn the logic or syntax  
Thank you